# navigator.mediaDevices is undefined with Chrome 78 on iOs 13

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, webrtc, mediadevices

I'm using an **iPad 5th Gen running iOs 13** and when i'm going on this link : https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

- With **Chrome 78** it's **not working**
- With **Safari 13** it's **working**

`navigator.mediaDevices` seems to be **undefined** with **Chrome 78 on iOs 13** but it's **defined** with **Chrome 78 on Windows 10**...

Does anyone have the same issue ? Any alternative to make it works with Chrome on iOs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getUserMedia is not supported in WkWebView on iOS: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458.
There are no workarounds.